# Error reading file with accented vowels

Tags: python, utf-8

The following statement to fill a list from a file :

```
action = []

with open (os.getcwd() + "/files/" + "actions.txt") as temp:
         action = list (temp)
```

gives me the following error:

```
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode (data, self.errors, end)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can not decode byte 0xf1 in position 67: invalid continuation byte
```

if I add `errors = 'ignore'`:

```
action = []

with open (os.getcwd () + "/ files /" + "actions.txt", errors = 'ignore') as temp:
         action = list (temp)
```

Is read the file but not the `ñ` and vowels accented `á-é-í-ó-ú` being that python 3 works, as I have understood, default to 'utf-8'

I'm looking for a solution for two or more days, and I'm getting more confused.

In advance thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Marking an answer as accepted is perfectly sufficient; there is no benefit from adding "(Solved)" to the title.

Comment: Ok tripleee, I thought it was better that way, then I have to edit my other questions that I got a satisfactory answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `codecs` to open the file with the correct encoding.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(os.getcwd () + "/ files /" + "actions.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as temp:
    action = list(temp)
```

See the [codecs docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html)

Comment: Just a note: from the question it seems that OP uses Py3, in which ``open`` has ``encoding`` keyword parameter. Also, ``utf8`` is the default encoding anyway; the OP's problem seems to be that his file is **not** ``utf8``.

Comment: Thank you very much, super fast response, 
you are wonderful people.

Now I'm trying to see if the file is successfully read,
gave me no error.

Answer (score 2):

As @Bogdan pointed out, you're likely not dealing with utf-8 data.  You can leverage a module like [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to try to determine the encoding.  If you're on a unix-y environment, you can also try running the `file` command on it to guess the encoding.

Using your error message character:

```
>>> import chardet
>>> sample_string = '\xf1'
>>> chardet.detect(sample_string)
{'confidence': 0.5, 'encoding': 'windows-1252'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much once again Kevin Stone

In fact it is, then I tried instead of encoding = "utf8" with encoding = "latin-1" and it worked wonders,

thank you very much for this last data, when I meet another problem I can find the coding problematic with your advice.

Comment: When I print in tkinter phrases taken from the text files, I get a square at the end, Have you any idea that can be? I am making an artificial intelligence program and the responses recorded in the archives, these squares appear, and produces a program untidiness

Comment: Usually a square indicates that your terminal or other display can't render the glyph for that character.  You'll have to determine what the character is and how to update the display to support it (sorry, I don't really know tkinter).

Comment: Hi Kevin, I finally managed to remove the square at the end of the text with this statement:

           resp1 = resp1.rstrip()

it was simple, right?

I hope my experience will serve others.

kind regards